# JSF 1.2 Error handling with IceFaces 1.8

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, icefaces, custom-error-pages, icefaces-1.8

my project is on JSF 1.2 and IceFaces. It works perfectly. I thought of adding error pages, to avoid showing that ugly exceptions page.
This is what I did :

web.xml

```
<error-page>
   <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
   <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

error.xhml

```
<html>
<body>
    <center>
    <h1> HELLO THIS IS AN ERROR</h1>
    </center>
</body>
```

I made a link in the application that generates the exception. But when I click on it, I just get nothing, neither the Hello message, neither the classic exception stack trace message.

Should I add some code to FacesConfig or something?

Comment: If this is the Apache MyFaces JSF implementation there some [additional configuration options](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MYFACES/Handling+Server+Errors).

Comment: So, when I have the exception, and the error.xhtml doesn't exist. 
There are 2 cases here : I let the web.xml error page declaration, or not. When I let it, I get the same thing, when I remove it, I get the "ugly exceptions page". 
So you maybe think I've put on the web.xml, the wrong path. Well I used the WTP editor to select the error.xhtml. Maybe that gave me something wrong. Do you want me to show my web.xml and faces-cong.xml files?
Thank you.

Comment: No, as mentioned it's IceFaces, I think that there's kind of exception handler but I don't know how to declare it.